# vue dialog doesn't close/hide

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I can't close or hide my vue-dialog and I don't know why. This is my js file from which I call the dialog:

```
<ItemChooserDialog v-model="showItemChooser" @onItemSelected="onStockSelected" />

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            showItemChooser: false,
        }
    }),
    methods: {
      chooseItem(context) {
        var self = this;
        self.showItemChooser = true;
      },
      onStockSelected(result) {
        var self = this;

        let id = result.id;
        let name = result.name;
        self.showItemChooser = false;
      },
   }
```

and this is my Dialog:

```
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="show" max-width="600">
      ...
    </v-dialog>
</template>

computed: {
   show: {
      get () {
        return this.value
      },
      set (value) {
         this.$emit('input', value)
      }
   }
},
props: {
    value: Boolean
},
methods: {
   rowClick{
     this.$emit('onItemSelected', clicked_item);
   }
}
```

If I choose an item in the dialog the callback-method "onStockSelected" of the js file runs and self.showItemChooser is set to false but the dialog is still visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any code that actually hides the dialog. The most common way to conditionally hide/show an element is to use the [v-if directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html).

On your dialog element:

```
<template>
    <v-dialog v-if="value" v-model="show" max-width="600">
      ...
    </v-dialog>
</template>
```

Comment: Actually, that's not about right. What controls if a dialogs is shown or hide is the boolean value you pass to it's **v-model**

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, v-model is only used to two-way bind the value in your html element to the data in your model. What you DO with that data is totally up to you. I don't see anything in the docs about v-model automatically hiding or showing a dialog if the value is a boolean. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: That's because he's using vuetify.js, which is a vue UI library with premade components. In this case, on the v-dialog docs. You can see that it's prop **value**, controls whether the component is visible or hidden. Which is in essence the v-model. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-dialog/#props

Answer (score 1):

Check this codesandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-70146776-6tczf?file=/src/components/ItemChooserDialog.vue

I can see you may took as example one of my previous answers. In this case, since you're using the prop **value** of your custom dialog component to handle the v-dialog v-model. You can close the dialog in two ways.

1. Closing the dialog from the parent component by setting up your **showItemChooser** to false. As you're doing on your example. Which I think it's not working because you declared your rowClick method without parentheses in your child component.

Also on my example I decided to use kebab-case on my event name but that just a convention from eslint. Everything else looks alright.

```js
      onStockSelected(result) {
        var self = this;
        let id = result.id;
        let name = result.name;
        self.showItemChooser = false;
      },
```

2. Closing the dialog from the child component. Since you're using the computer property **show** on the v-model of your v-dialog. You can close the dialog by simply setting the show value to false.

```js
    closeFromChild() {
      this.show = false
    }
```

Last but not least, v-dialog's by default close themselves if you click outside the dialog. If you want to avoid this functionality you can set the **persistent** prop to your dialog as I did on my example.